# CakeDC Users - Custom Configuration issues

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakedc

I've added a permission to my permissions.php file: Users.Username.displayed = true/false so that I can decide whether or not I want to use usernames, or just stick to email + real names depending on my application.

I've got this all set up and working well for registering users, and it does all the right things in terms of field validation etc whether or not it is set to display.

Now I want to hide/show the field in my CRUD files too (index, add, edit) but I cant seem to get it to work.

At the top of my SimpleCrudTrait.php file I added

```
use Cake\Core\Configure;
```

but in my view Templates (index, add, edit) if I try to call

```
if(Configure::read('Users.Username.displayed'){ ...
```

I get an error

```
Class 'Configure' not found
```

I can't figure out why this is working for register but not the other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You've presumably not included the `use` line in your templates. It needs to be present in every file where you want to reference the `Configure` class. Read up on PHP namespaces for more details.

Comment: As per above I have included it

Comment: You said you included it in SimpleCrudTrait.php. Have you included it in index.ctp, add.ctp and edit.ctp?